# lein ring server-headless fails when including datomic dependency

Tags: clojure, compojure, ring, datomic

My goal is to create a web application using compojure and attach datomic as database. Individually, these two components work fine. However, when I try to start the server with 
`lein ring server-headless` (including datomic as a dependency) with an enourmous error. The head of the error output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/util/component/AggregateLifeCycle, compiling:(ring/adapter/jetty.clj:1:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7391)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:372)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:363)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:453)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:419)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5677.invoke(core.clj:5893)
```

using the `project.clj`

```
(defproject pinvest "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "foobar"
  :min-lein-version "2.0.0"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                 [org.clojure/core.async "0.3.442"]
                 [org.clojure/tools.namespace "0.2.11"]
                 [compojure "1.5.1"]
                 [ring/ring-defaults "0.2.1"]
                 [com.datomic/clj-client "0.8.606"]]
  :plugins [[lein-ring "0.9.7"]]
  :ring {:handler pinvest.handler/app}
  :profiles
  {:dev {:dependencies [[javax.servlet/servlet-api "2.5"]
                        [ring/ring-mock "0.3.0"]]}})
```

Initially generated with `lein new compojure foo`. The dependency `com.datomic/clj-client` is causing the problem in starting the server.

I tried excluding some dependencies, by making my `project.clj` with

```
[com.datomic/clj-client "0.8.606"
    :exclusions [org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-http
                 org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-util
                 org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-client]]
```

but that just results in

```
clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient, compiling:(cognitect/http_client.clj:1:1)
```

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

PS. I'm a newbie to clojure, and these error messages are just impossible to understand

Comment: Which version of jetty is `com.datomic/clj-client "0.8.606"` supposed to work with?

Comment: using `lein deps :tree` gives me 
 [org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-client "9.3.7.v20160115][org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-io "9.3.7.v20160115"][org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-http "9.3.7.v20160115"][org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-util "9.3.7.v20160115"]

Comment: Can you see the AggregateLifeCycle class file in a jar file in your local .m2 maven repo? If it does not exist in one of the jar files pointed to (probably jetty-util) then the error message makes sense.

Comment: I checked all jar  files in the m2 repository. It turns out `org/eclipse/jetty-util/ contains two versions. 7.6.13.v20130916 and 9.3.7.v20160115. only the 7.x version contains the AggregateLifeCycle class file.

Comment: How would I go about resolving this dependency problem?

Comment: I also know that my ring version is using the 7.x version of jetty

Comment: Just for debugging could you go into .m2 and deactivate the version (9.3.7) that doesn't have `AggregateLifeCycle.class`. By say replacing the jar with an empty jar - some way to find out what is bringing in 9.3.7 - the `jetty-util` you want to get rid of. Then maybe you could go to a previous version of the thing that depends on 9.3.7, to attempt to get rid of this triangular dependency problem. I would have thought `lein deps :tree` would show the exact problem - what needs 9.3.7. You need to either downgrade it (so `jetty-util` is downgraded too), or exclude its dependency on `jetty-util`.

Comment: The thing that is requiring the 9.3.7 version is `com.datomic/clj-client`. This library is provided via the [maven central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22clj-client%22). It only seems to show the latest version of the package though. Do you know how to get earlier versions?

Comment: Take a look here: https://clojurians-log.clojureverse.org/datomic/2016-12-21.html. You should probably join the Datomic Slack group and ask there.

Answer (score 1):

Try not to use jetty. Someone from the Slack group who came up with a very similar problem now uses this combination (http-kit in place of jetty):

`[com.datomic/datomic-free "0.9.5544"] [ring/ring-core "1.5.0"] [http-kit "2.2.0"]`

Comment: the datomic clj-client depends on jetty. If I'm purging jetty, I'm getting `CompilerException java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient, compiling:(cognitect/http_client.clj:1:1)`

Comment: This solution worked for me. I had the same problem as the OP.

Comment: Hmmm... so it didn't work after I switched from datomic-free to datomic client (clj-client) and I need to use the client library.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue too and could find no workaround. From what I understand it looks like ring-core is using an older jetty adapter for legacy purposes. I've found https://github.com/sunng87/ring-jetty9-adapter a worthy replacement as a ring dependancy so far with no further issues in my setup:

```
[com.datomic/clj-client "0.8.606" :exclusions [org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-http org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-util org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-client]]
[info.sunng/ring-jetty9-adapter "0.10.0"]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's odd. The `:exclusion` worked for me(but I see it did not work for you). It's documented [here](https://docs.datomic.com/cloud/troubleshooting.html#dependency-conflict)

```
[com.datomic/client-pro "0.8.28"
                    :exclusions [org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-client
                                org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-http
                                org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-util]]
```